# windows S2022 net use cannot accept Azure storage key because it starts with slash AND sshd limitations

Tags: azure-storage-account, windows-server-2022

I wish to attach a network drive/share from a session created via `sshd`.  The drive was originally created with the standard Powershell connect script provided on the "Connect" tab as executed in a Powershell window in RDP.  The drive persists and the W2022 instance can be stopped and restarted and `Z:` drive reappears in Powershell windows launched inside RDP.  My question concerns connecting to `Z:` from shells launched from `sshd`.

The command

```
net use Z: \\myStorageAcct.file.core.windows.net\xfer /user:myStorageAcct
```

prompts for a password and I enter the storage account secret key -- which starts with a slash -- and everything works.   The `net use` command can take the password on the command line but I cannot figure out how to pass the password without `net use` interpreting the password as an option, e.g.:

```
net use Z: \\myStorageAcct.file.core.windows.net\xfer /user:myStorageAcct   /CMA33FV...==
The option /CMA33FV...== is unknown
```

I am open to Powershell tricks or a util other than `net use` to attach the drive.

### EDIT

Important constraint:  Sessions created with `sshd` cannot use the standard Powershell script that appears in the "Connect" tab of the file share.   In particular, the `cmdkey` exec produces this error:

```
CMDKEY: Credentials cannot be saved from this logon session.
```

Comment: If you go to azure file share and you click on connect you get a PowerShell script there which you can use to connect.
Assuming you want to connect to an azure file share

Comment: I accidentally deleted several sentences about how launching from `sshd` shells is different than `RDP`.  The standard connect script does not work from `sshd` shells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logging in with either name+password or a keypair via `sshd` yields a restricted session that requires additional authentication to access remote resources.  One way or another, you will have to provide credentials to attach the drive.  These can be supplied in a script, the environment, a key vault, etc. but the essence of the solution is:

```
$username = "myStorageAcct"

# Not the session login; this is storage account secret key:
$password = "/CMA43ydVvM4N..."  

$secureStringPwd = $password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force

#  The Juice:
$creds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $username, $secureStringPwd
New-PSDrive -Name Z -PSProvider FileSystem -Root "\\myStorageAcct.file.core.windows.net\myShareName" -Credential $creds
```

By specifying a credential object, `New-PSDrive` avoids the leading slash problem encountered with `net use` where the password is mistaken for an option.

Answer (score 1):

> I am open to PowerShell tricks or a util other than `net use` to attach the drive.

To attach a network drive from a file share, I agree with Turdie's comment. You can copy the PowerShell script from the file share through the portal.

***Portal -> Your storage account -> fileshare -> your fileshare -> connect -> windows -> copy script***

**Portal:**

[image]

> **Note:** The script will only work on Windows Server 2012 and above.

Now, I copied the script and pasted it into my Windows Server 2022 PowerShell, as shown below:

**Script:**

```
$connectTestResult = Test-NetConnection -ComputerName venkat789.file.core.windows.net -Port 445
if ($connectTestResult.TcpTestSucceeded) {
    # Save the password so the drive will persist on reboot
    cmd.exe /C "cmdkey /add:`"venkat789.file.core.windows.net`" /user:`"localhost\venkat789`" /pass:`"xxxxxxx`""
    # Mount the drive
    New-PSDrive -Name Z -PSProvider FileSystem -Root "\\venkat789.file.core.windows.net\share1" -Persist
} else {
    Write-Error -Message "Unable to reach the Azure storage account via port 445. Check to make sure your organization or ISP is not blocking port 445, or use Azure P2S VPN, Azure S2S VPN, or Express Route to tunnel SMB traffic over a different port."
}
```

**Output:**
[image]

The above script executed and attached a network drive/file share to my Windows Server 2022.

[image]

**Reference:**

[Mount SMB Azure file share on Windows | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-windows)

Comment: Please see edit in original question above.   This approach will not work for shells created from `sshd`.